# Fixed position on desktop browsers, relative/static position on mobile devices (Android, iOS ...)

Tags: jquery, css

A few days ago i run into a problem that i did not imagine that exists regarding fixed position. I have searched and i have found a few articles regarding this (best described is http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/ ) and it seems that no viable solution exist.

On short, i want to have a fixed nav and a side block as you can see bellow (the code works perfect on desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE8) ), that shows and works like that only on desktop browsers. If a mobile device browser is used like Android, iOS, Windows Mobile eg), the fixed position for nav and sidebar should be changed in static or relative, to make those 2 blocks scroll up with the rest of the page.

Solutions via media queries are not ok because they target device screen and not actual device/browser.

Can this be done? I would appreciate a jsfiddle to test it with mobile devices. Thanks

```js
var win      = $(window),
    fxel     = $('nav'),
    eloffset = fxel.offset().top;

win.scroll(function() {
    if (eloffset < win.scrollTop()) {
        fxel.addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        fxel.removeClass("fixed");
    }
});

/*!
 * StickySidebar jQuery Plugin v1.0.1
 * Copyright 2014 Dawid Pawelec
 * Released under the MIT license
 */

(function ($) {
    var $w = $(window);

    $.fn.stickySidebar = function (options) {
        var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.stickySidebar.defaults, options),
            $c = $(o.container);

        return this.each(function () {
            var $s = $(this),
                sh = $s.outerHeight(),
                originalMarginTop = parseInt($s.css('margin-top'), 10),
                top = $s.offset().top - o.offsetTop - originalMarginTop,
                bottom = $c.offset().top + $c.outerHeight() - o.offsetTop,

                handleScroll = function () {
                    var scroll = $w.scrollTop();
                    if (scroll > top) {
                        if (scroll + sh + o.offsetBottom > bottom && o.bottom) {
                            $s.removeClass(o.stuckClass);
                            $s.addClass(o.bottomClass);
                        } else {
                            $s.css('margin-top', o.offsetTop + originalMarginTop);
                            $s.addClass(o.stuckClass);
                        }
                    } else {
                        $s.css('margin-top', originalMarginTop);
                        $s.removeClass(o.stuckClass);
                        $s.removeClass(o.bottomClass);
                    }
                };

            $w.on('scroll', handleScroll);
        });

    };

    $.fn.stickySidebar.defaults = {
        stuckClass: 'fixed',
        bottomClass: 'bottom',
        container: '.container',
        offsetTop: 80,
        offsetBottom: 0,
        bottom: true
    };

}(jQuery));



// Usage
$('.sidebar').stickySidebar({
    container: '.container',
    offsetBottom: 5
});
```

```css
.header, .footer {
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px
}
.header-top {height:50px;}
.header-bottom {height:60px;}
.header {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    height: 120px;
}

.container {
    background: #ddd;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.sidebar, .main-content {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px;
}

.sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 169px;
    height: 200px;
}

.sidebar.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.sidebar.bottom {
    bottom: 5px;
}

.main-content {
    margin-left: 205px;
    width: 253px;
    height: 2000px;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.footer {
    height: 500px;
}

nav {
  height:50px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}

nav.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-top">Header</div>
    <div class="header-bottom"><nav>Sticky!</nav> </div>
    </header>
   
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
        <div class="main-content">Main</div>
    </div>
    
    <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by inserting all the jquery code between
if( /Windows|OS X/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
ALL JQUERY CODE
}

This way, all is working properly (tested on windows - Chrome/IE8/Firefox; osx laptop -Safari/Chrome/Firefox; Android tablet)